# Is it possible to download an object as a file from google colab WITHOUT first saving it as a file to google drive?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to download a pandas dataframe directly from colab's memory INSTEAD of saving that dataframe to drive as a csv then using the files library to download that file.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10))

data.to_csv()
```

This block of code generates a formatted example I just need something that will give me a dialog box so I can save that object locally.

The reason behind this is I'm developing a shared notebook that others will use to generate data and I don't want have the users saving all kinds of stuff to my drive. Is what I'm asking for currently possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are several options:

1. Use the `google.colab.files` module to download like so:

```
    from google.colab import files
    files.download('csv')
```

2. Right click on the file in the file browser and select download like so:

[image]

Comment: okay this might work but when you mount drive before you write the csv will that write the file to the top level of your drive or does it just stay in the colab vm? i'll test it now and see what happens.